# Jannah, it's levels and the extent to which wishes shall be fulfilled

Tags: jannah

Will there be levels in jannah?

I have heard that all wishes would be accepted in jannah so if I wish myself to be at a upper level of jannah will I be granted that?

I wish to know more about jannah levels.

Let's say I wasn't that good and went to a lower level but after staying there for a long time will I be able to move to another level, like those people who would come out of hell after their punishment is over? Not getting full benefits or enjoyment is also a sort of punishment.

Answer (score 1):

**will there be levels in jannah?**

Yes, According to some verses like the one quoted below, Paradise does have different levels:

> لَّا يَسْتَوِي الْقَاعِدُونَ مِنَ الْمُؤْمِنِينَ غَيْرُ‌ أُولِي
>   الضَّرَ‌رِ‌ وَالْمُجَاهِدُونَ فِي سَبِيلِ اللَّـهِ بِأَمْوَالِهِمْ
>   وَأَنفُسِهِمْ ۚ فَضَّلَ اللَّـهُ الْمُجَاهِدِينَ بِأَمْوَالِهِمْ
>   وَأَنفُسِهِمْ عَلَى الْقَاعِدِينَ دَرَ‌جَةً ۚ وَكُلًّا وَعَدَ اللَّـهُ
>   الْحُسْنَىٰ ۚ وَفَضَّلَ اللَّـهُ الْمُجَاهِدِينَ عَلَى الْقَاعِدِينَ
>   أَجْرً‌ا عَظِيمًا
>
> Not equal are those believers remaining [at home] - other than the
>   disabled - and the mujahideen, [who strive and fight] in the cause of
>   Allah with their wealth and their lives. Allah has preferred the
>   mujahideen through their wealth and their lives over those who remain
>   [behind], by degrees. And to both Allah has promised the best
>   [reward]. But Allah has preferred the mujahideen over those who remain
>   [behind] with a great reward -  http://tanzil.net/#4:95
>
> وَمَا أَمْوَالُكُمْ وَلَا أَوْلَادُكُم بِالَّتِي تُقَرِّ‌بُكُمْ
>   عِندَنَا زُلْفَىٰ إِلَّا مَنْ آمَنَ وَعَمِلَ صَالِحًا فَأُولَـٰئِكَ
>   لَهُمْ جَزَاءُ الضِّعْفِ بِمَا عَمِلُوا وَهُمْ فِي الْغُرُ‌فَاتِ
>   آمِنُونَ
>
> And it is not your wealth or your children that bring you nearer to
>   Us in position, but it is [by being] one who has believed and done
>   righteousness. For them there will be the double reward for what they
>   did, and they will be in the upper chambers [of Paradise], safe [and
>   secure].  http://tanzil.net/#34:37

**I heard all wishes would be accepted in jannah so i wish myself to be upper level of jannah will i be granted that.**

In paradise people are completely unaware of existence of a higher level and anything about upper levels is removed from their minds. Since this is the key of harm when you see people having some things better than you don't have. The wishes are limited to those things which will be available in that particular level one is in. In fact you will never wish of anything unseen or have any unawareness of them. For example, a baby never wishes to have sex because it has no awareness of such a phenomenon. Or a man who is living alone in an island and has never seen or heard anything about *grapes* will never have wish for them.

**And could you tell more about jannah levels.**

Usually it is said levels of paradise are equal to the number of verses in Quran and by knowing and practicing a verse in life one goes to higher level. In fact who knows, obeys and practices all verses of the Quran during his life will reach the highest level of paradise. Only reading or memorizing Quran is not enough, although memorizing them has its benefits.

**Let's say I wasn't that good and went to lower level but after living long time there will i be able to move to another level, as people would come out of hell after their punishment is over. Not getting full benefits or enjoyment is also sort of punishment in a way.**

Yes but this is if the person is aware of the existence of a higher level. Your mind is under the control of God and God can clear anything from the mind of people and does it in this world as well when God wants to interfere in regular happenings of the world and assist his messengers and friends.

> فَلَا تَعْلَمُ نَفْسٌ مَّا أُخْفِيَ لَهُم مِّن قُرَّ‌ةِ أَعْيُنٍ
>   جَزَاءً بِمَا كَانُوا يَعْمَلُونَ
>
> No person knows what is kept hidden for them of joy as a reward for
>   what they used to do. http://tanzil.net/#32:17

Comment: "In paradise people are completely unaware of existence of a higher level"...how can you say that...like is there any reference for it. I have heard hadith that i think roughly meant minds will work just as they do here but without all negativity. so if while on earth we know that there are levels, why won't we remember it there. Also, not knowing what's in the higher levels doesn't mean i don't know of them. Like a man who has heard that there're other kinds of fruits and has never seen grapes, yes he doesn't know what grapes is, but he knows there is more...

Comment: yes minds work. but somethings are removed from mind. here also somethings are removed from our mind. one negativity is looking at people at higher level having enjoys you do not have. paradise is different of here. higher level means more enjoys. greater homes,... for example some levels have hoori http://tanzil.net/#56:22 and some do not have but have their own wife in this world:http://tanzil.net/#56:36 in paradise they do not know there is a higher level. each person is in his own garden:http://tanzil.net/#3:133 and is busy enjoying in his own garden: http://tanzil.net/#36:55

Comment: so what if i wish, i want everything that the best person in jannah has. Even though i didn't wish for what i don't know but that doesn't mean i don't know of it.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer your mind before entering to paradise will be changed and you will forget anything you know about higher levels. it is like when an old man wants to enter paradise becomes young. human change before enter. there is a pool called "the life pool" everyone swim in it and become young and white and with a clear mind and then enter. you both do not know and do not wish. if you know you will wish and not having it is an annoy and there is no annoy there. and all are not in top level. this is not fair. sura waqiah clearly says Muqarabin are higher than right people. so all are not same

Comment: I'm Back after one year, i kept forgetting each time i used internet. But here i'm now. you said that minds will be changed as so that ill forget everything about higher levels. But that's not what i read. I specifically remember reading that people in higher level of janna will look like stars to people in lower level and they will wish, we could be there. (how come? i read a) there will be no sorrows in jannah. b) all wishes will be granted so how come this isn't happening.)

Comment: You say: "In paradise people are completely unaware of existence of a higher level".... but it contradicts: “The people of Paradise will see the people of the highest places in Paradise above them as you see a brilliant star far away on the horizon in the east or the west, because of the difference in status between them.”

Answer (score -1):

In Jannah, everyone will be content with what they have. Allah Ta'ala will remove any ill-feeling, remorse, regret, and envy from the hearts of Jannatis so even though people of the lower level will meet people from the higher levels inshaa Allah, there will be no envy between them. Allah is the Just. Would u feel Allah is Just, if He Ta'ala, was to admit u (a born Muslim who worshipped Allah Ta'ala ur entire life) to the same Jannah with, for example, a person who worshipped idols his entire life but only reverted to Islam and worshipped Allah for only two days and then died? U would say this is injustice but Allah Ta'ala is Al Adl (the just). This is just an example think of other examples.

Comment: Please take the time to write clearly and with proper grammar; poor writing and "text-speak" abbreviations are considered low-quality here and detract from the professional nature of this site.