# Would people from lower level Jannah able to travel to higher level Jannah?

Tags: jannah, akhirah

Would people from lower level Jannah able to travel to higher level Jannah? I don't mean move to higher level Jannah permanently, just travel there then comeback to your place in lower level Jannah.  I am asking this because if you are in lower level Jannah and you have someone you know in higher level Jannah and you want to visit them, can you do that?

Comment: If your question is about whether you can permanently move to a higher level of Jannah, like some people in Hell will go to Jannah after their punishment, then your question is answered [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10075/jannah-its-levels-and-the-extent-to-which-wishes-shall-be-fulfilled), if your question is about if you could just travel there and then come back to the lower level of Jannah, like a trip, then I suggest you make your question a bit clearer.

Answer (score -4):

To get a detailed explanation, please refer to this site.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/126349

Comment: This is a link only answer see in [our meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/953/the-copy-paste-issue-revisited).

Comment: The link my answer the question but your post don't.